# C : String comparing

Tags: c, linux

```
bool done;
done = false;
while (!done) {
    /* read the message */
    bzero(msg, 100);
    printf("[client]Type something: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    read(0, msg, 100);
    if (strcmp(msg, "/done") == 0) {
        done = true;
        /* sending the message to the server */
        if (write(sd, msg, 100) <= 0) {
            perror("[client]Error sending the message to the server.\n");
            return errno;
        }
    } else {
        /* sending the message to the server */
        if (write(sd, msg, 100) <= 0) {
            perror("[client]Error sending the message to the server.\n");
            return errno;

        /* reading the answer given by the server*/
        if (read(sd, msg, 100) < 0) {
            perror("[client]read() error from server.\n");
            return errno;
        }
        /* printing the received message */
        printf("[client]The received message is: %s\n", msg);
    }
}
```

Here's the code that i have problem with. So i want to send messages to the server until I send the message "/done", the code works, I send messages continuously but even when i type and send "/done" the process doesn't end.

I think there's a problem with the bzero function that "clears" the msg or maybe i don't understand it so good.

I also tried to wrote my own function to check if two strings are the same, but no effect also.

So how should i write the condition or "clear" the msg so i can send messages continuously and after i send "/done" the execution ends?

P.S. the msg is declared earlier in the code as char msg[100];

Comment: and what did you see was happening when you stepped through the code with your debugger?

Comment: `bzero()` is deprecated (by POSIX), and was never specified by the C language standard.  You should use `memset()` instead.  I don't think that's the source of your problem, however.

Comment: Is the return value of `read(0, msg, 100);` _always_ as expected?

Comment: testing the result of read would be a good idea. Adn why are you using such a low level function to read stdin.

Comment: What message protocol are you using? Is this connected UDP? UNIX domain? Are you reading from a pipe? I hope this isn't TCP!

Comment: `strcmp(msg, "/done")` is a problem  when `read(0, msg, 100)` reads 100 characters as `msg` is not certainly a _string_.

Comment: Given that you are using a low-level I/O function (`read`) It seems likely that the problem is that you're getting more than you expect -- a trailing newline, for example.  That would make your input compare unequal to the test string.

Comment: @chux yes it is.

Comment: @John Bollinger i was thinking about it but i don't know how else can i send messages of different sizes and then reuse the variable for a next message also. I will try with memset, and i will come back.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is TCP indeed.

Comment: @pm100 i have to use primitives as this is a school project.

Comment: @Dragomas, I was not suggesting that you should avoid `read()`, but rather that you should pay more attention to exactly what you have read.  Nevertheless, if you are using an implementation that provides [`fdopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen), then it might be that using that to boost yourself into stream I/O instead of raw I/O would make your life easier.  Of course, that supposes that your file descriptor 0 is not already connected to the standard input, so that you could just go straight to using `stdin`.

Comment: @Dragomas Oh, no! TCP is not a message protocol. If you're going to use TCP to send and receive messages, you have to design (or choose) and implement a message protocol on top of TCP. What if `read` returns 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read from 0, you're reading from stdin.  If that is a terminal that you are typing into (you don't say), you likely have it set up in normal (canonical) mode, so you'll read a line, which probably includes a newline (\n) character.  So when you enter `/done`, the string you get in your msg buffer is `"/done\n"` which doesn't match `"/done"`...

Answer (score 0):

read(2) is including the '\n' at the end of the string. When you use low-level read you get everything. When trying to debug strings, it can be helpful to put quotes in your print statement, like

```
printf("[client]The received message is: '%s'\n", msg);
```

as this immediately shows invisible whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not a message protocol. It does *not* glue bytes together into messages. If you want to use TCP to send and receive messages, you'll need to implement functions that send and receive messages.

I must strongly caution you not to fail into the trap of thinking that changing your code from happening not to work when you tried it to happening to work when you try it means that you've fixed it. Your code fails if `read` returns 1. You need to implement a sensible function to receive a message or your code will only be working by luck, and I can tell you from painful experience that one day your luck will run out.